# Visual Studio 2019 won't update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 v16.1.6 installed on my Windows 10 x64 machine. My Visual Studio installer doesn't find any updates and thinks that 16.1.6 is the latest version. I've tried deleting the Visual Studio installer folder — which triggers a reinstall of it — but to no avail. I've also tried uninstalling VS, which didn't work.

Anyone had a problem like this before? My machine was re-imaged recently and it's possible a prerequisite for upgrading VS is missing. Could there be a windows patch or other software I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Update your Visual Studio *Installer* first, then you can update Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself. The installer was reading a json file on my work's network to check for updates, rather than going out to the web. Fixed it by deleting a registry key pointing to the local network location.